# Error - Highlight the active/current (pressed) button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, shopify, liquid

[Menu item Active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOOsm.png)

The above image is how the header menu supposed to work on click/active state.

[Menu item not Active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQkte.png)

The image above is active one the second header menu "MEN" but the highlight below the title is not active.

About this project. Its a shopify purchased theme. The first image is from the live demo, where it works fine. The second image is the theme added to shopify.

The active state is defined in "header-e-cormmerce.liquid"

I have very little knowledge about development. Apologies if my question or explanation is amateur.

[How it suppose to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1zUv.gif)

[How its working now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOdsG.gif)

Answer (score 0):

If the class is correctly applied to the active menu item, but the highlight is not showing, there may be an issue with the CSS styles. You can try the following steps to troubleshoot the problem:

Make sure that the CSS file where the provided code is located (header-e-commerce.liquid) is properly included in your Shopify theme. Check that the file is being loaded correctly and that there are no errors or conflicts in the CSS code.

Inspect the active menu item using your browser's developer tools. Look for any conflicting CSS styles that may be overriding or hiding the highlight effect. Pay attention to any other CSS rules that target the same elements or pseudo-elements (:after, :before) and might interfere with the active state styles.

Check if there are any JavaScript or jQuery scripts running on your Shopify theme that may be modifying or interfering with the active state styles. Disable or temporarily remove any such scripts to see if it resolves the issue.

If you're still experiencing difficulties, it would be helpful to provide the relevant HTML code and any additional CSS or JavaScript code related to the header menu, so that I can assist you further in troubleshooting the problem.

Comment: tried everything. i have added two more images of what am trying to explain. and how it should work. Also, the CSS editing is limited, the file now i have is in liquid (shopify) code.